# DDD bounded context naming

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-architecture, bounded-contexts

Should bounded context names be plural or singular and why? For example, if I have car rental website should I have dealership bounded context or dealerships?

Answer (score 6):

In the original DDD text, the example bounded contexts are named for the theme of the activities within that context: Booking, Scheduling, Routing.

The names tend to be aligned with the natural language of the domain, so I would guess you are more likely to have a `Sales` domain than you are a `Selling` domain, `Reservations` rather than `Reserving` (but see also Booking), and so on.

A `Dealership` domain, either singular or plural, doesn't sound like a theme of activities, but rather a model.  The associated bounded context might be Advertising/Marketing, or it might be Sales? might be some Inventory there as well.  If the you are renting commercial vehicles, that might be an entirely separate context.

For more detail, see Domain Driven Design: Tackling Complexity at the Heart of Software, Chapter 14.